# HTML form / PHP get input text LIVE

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using a HTML form for making a search field to my database via PHP. It works right now, when i enter text and press a button. But i want to make the results dynamic and show up as the user types. How do i get the textInput from the form live? without having to wait for the user to press a button and submit the text.

The HTML text field:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

    <button class="fa fa-search button" name ="submit" type="submit"></button>
    <input class="search" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Søg">
</form>
```

The PHP script where i search the database and print the results:

```
<?php
    $search = $_POST["input"];
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<h2> Søgeresultater </h2>";
        $sql = "SELECT name, description, price, image, stock FROM products WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR LOWER(description) LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<br>" . $row["name"]. ": " . $row["description"] ." - Price: " . $row["price"] . " DKK" . " Lagerstatus: ". $row["stock"] . "<br>";
            echo '<img id="image"" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: your php script now readable

Comment: Why not do some ajax call in the button press event or do auto suggest ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I don't know how to do that. That is why i am asking :)

Comment: OK writing answer for you ;)

Comment: @CasperTL I've converted your images to actual code within the question for readability purposes (since the images were smaller). I took care to ensure the code matched the images exactly so as not to throw off the intent of the original question.

Comment: @War10ck Thank you! That was kind of you to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script you needed

Create two files named index.php your front page and search.php which acts as your request and response page

Here is the jquery you wanted, it triggers the function in keyup function, which will passes the value that you type to the search.php file

**Jquery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

**search.php**

The search.php file should be given enough db credentials as i have it in the file db.php. There the file is getting the input and matches with the db and sending you the response.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['search'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("select id,name,email from autocomplete where name like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$username=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$b_username='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$b_email='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
$final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
?>
<div class="show" align="left">
<img src="author.PNG" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" /><span class="name"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><?php echo $final_email; ?><br/>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

**Style and HTML**

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{ 
        font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:18px;
    }
    .content{
        width:900px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #searchid
    {
        width:500px;
        border:solid 1px #000;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    #result
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:500px;
        padding:10px;
        display:none;
        margin-top:-1px;
        border-top:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px #CCC solid;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .show
    {
        padding:10px; 
        border-bottom:1px #999 dashed;
        font-size:15px; 
        height:50px;
    }
    .show:hover
    {
        background:#4c66a4;
        color:#FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="content">
<input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Search for people" />&nbsp; &nbsp; Ex:arunkumar, shanmu, vicky<br /> 
<div id="result">
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks for your time! I am trying to figure out where in your code i define/assign the textfield ? :)

Comment: Just a quick note, [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in jQuery v1.7 and removed in v1.9. To ensure compatibility with future versions and in an effort to "future-proof" your code, you should change `.live()` to use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) which was added in jQuery v1.7.